# OrderBy with a dynamic string parameter in Lambda with related table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have a extention orderByField

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string 
SortField, bool Ascending){
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
        string method = Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, 
        q.Expression, exp);
        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
    }
```

I use it for pass string parameter in it

```
 string sortBy = "StatusID";
 return dbContext.Requests.OrderByField(sortBy,true)
```

But how i can orderBy with a dynamic string parameter with column related with request table like

```
  dbContext.Requests.OrderBy(x => x.Status.Description)
```

Comment: Seems like we're talking about recursive reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you would receive `SortField` argument in the form of `"Status.Description"`, you would:

- First have to split argument to get all properties
- Iterate over property names and building property accessor expressions
- Use built expression as body of lambda expression

For example:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string SortField, bool Ascending)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    Expression expBody = param;
    string[] props = SortField.Split('.');
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        expBody = Expression.Property(expBody, prop);
    }
    var exp = Expression.Lambda(expBody, param);
    string method = Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
    Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
    var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
    return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
}
```